# Getting the current Date from Firebase- Swift

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, timestamp, nsdate

I am trying to get the date from firebase, but I was unable to find any good sources because most of the posts are outdated...

I know that you have to get the timestamp from firebase, then you have to convert it to seconds (NSDate) because it's in millisecconds because of the epoch.

I'm not sure how to do this, I tried using the docs
[(firebaseTimestamp)](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/swift/firebasefirestore/api/reference/Classes/Timestamp), but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the link you provided. Get the timestamp from firebase and then call .dateValue() on the variable. The call would be something like:

let myDate: Date = timestamp.dateValue()

Comment: Yes, This is the answer to it. I was just confused on the part where you get the timestamp from the database.P.S. They recently changed the timestamp from Firebase.database.ServerValue.timestamp() to Firebase.ServerValue.timestamp(), Thanks for the help!